# Eliminar registro de una columna pandas si comienza por

Tags: python, pandas

Si dispongo de un df con una columna telefonos, tal que asi:

```
id     telefonos       calle

1      60000000       España
2      61111111       Chile
3      32332333       Alemania
4      75585547       Argentina
```

La idea es SIN hacerlo con un bucle, eliminar aquellos que comienzan por 3...

```
Esta es la salida que busco:(NaN o Blnaco)
id     telefonos       calle

1      60000000       España
2      61111111       Chile
3         NaN            Alemania
4      75585547       Argentina
```

He intentado algo asi sin exito:

df.drop(df.loc[(df.telefono.str[0:1]==3)].index, inplace=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construye tu columna de nuevo condicionando según el valor existente.

```
import numpy as np

df['telefonos'] = np.where(df['telefonos'].str.startswith('3'), np.nan, df['telefonos'])
```

El resultado será:

| id | telefonos | pais |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60000000 | España |
| 2 | 61111111 | Chile |
| 3 | nan | Alemania |
| 4 | 75585547 | Argentina |

Lo que haces es con `np.where()` condicionar el resultado en función de que se cumpla que el valor `telefonos` empiece por 3 `df['telefonos'].str.startswith('3')`.

Si es así devuelves `np.nan` y en caso contrario devuelves el valor existente en `telefonos`

Comment: Buenas, finalmente lo conseguí con una lambda pero esta opción es mas eficaz! Gracias